# ImageButton in asp doesn't fire on onclick event

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, imagebutton

Environment: VS2012, jquery and VB code Behind
It's a simple imageButton in

```
<td><asp:imageButton onClick="Function generated by vs" ..>
```

When the client click on this no event is fired.
The same problem persists with another code using listview with updatePanel and trigger imageButton.

This code works when I use a simple Html page but does not work when I have a master page ?

```
<table id="tableImg" class="tableImage">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="PagerLeft" CssClass="divPagerLeft"
                    ImageUrl="~/Medias/Config/SliderMoveLeft.gif"
                    OnClick="PagerLeft_Click"
                    runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td class='tdImage'>
            <asp:Image ID="img1" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgIntoGallery" ImageUrl="/" AlternateText="img1" runat="server" />
        </td>

        <td class='tdImage'>
            <asp:Image ID="img2" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgIntoGallery" ImageUrl="/" AlternateText="img1" runat="server" />
        </td>

        <td class='tdImage'>
            <asp:Image ID="img3" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgIntoGallery" ImageUrl="/" AlternateText="img1" runat="server" />
        </td>

        <td class='tdImage'>
            <asp:Image ID="img4" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgIntoGallery" ImageUrl="/" AlternateText="img1" runat="server" />
        </td>

        <td class='tdImage'>
            <asp:Image ID="img5" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgIntoGallery" ImageUrl="/" AlternateText="img1" runat="server" />
        </td>

        <td class='tdImage'>
            <asp:Image ID="img6" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="imgIntoGallery" ImageUrl="/" AlternateText="img1" runat="server" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="PagerRight" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="divPagerRight"
                 ImageUrl="~/Medias/Config/SliderMoveRight.gif"
                 OnClick="PagerRight_Click"
                 runat="server" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



CODE BEHIND :-

Protected Sub btnRight_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.[GetType](), "alert", "alert('RightClick')", True)
    Dim start_index As Integer = 0
    If (ViewState("start_index") Is Nothing) Then
        ViewState("start_index") = 0
    Else
        start_index = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState("start_index"))
    End If
    If (start_index < nbrRows - PageSize) Then
        start_index += 1
        ViewState("start_index") = start_index
        idxFrom = start_index
        idxTo = idxFrom + PageSize
        getImgFromSql()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the code for the event handlers than that both PagerLeft and PageRight. You have posted code for a btnRight which doesn't exist on your aspx page, it also doesn't seem to handle a click event.

To handle a click event of a button you can always declare the function as follows:

```
Public Sub PagerLeft_Click(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PagerClick.Click
    'Do code
End Sub
```

Doing this you could remove the OnClick text from your HTML, as this will be fired automatically as the OnClick HTML will be generated by the server automatically before the page is rendered.

Are you able to confirm if you have defined these click event methods?

Answer (score 0):

The Onclick="Event" needs to be the name of the sub in code-behind. For instance the PagerRight's Onclick event would need to be changed to btnRight_Click for that sub to be called.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="PagerRight" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="divPagerRight"
                 ImageUrl="~/Medias/Config/SliderMoveRight.gif"
                 **Onclick="btnRight_Click"**
                 runat="server" />
```

An alternative would to remove the Onclick from the imagebutton and type Handles PagerRight.Click at the end of the Sub line.

```
Protected Sub btnRight_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PagerRight.Click

End Sub
```